# Detect when user is selecting text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a RichTextBox in my application to show the user an activity log, this RichTextBox is updated automatically when a new event happens.

So my problem is... one of my coworkers is visually impaired, so I've implemented a way so that when he select a fragment of text, that fragment of text is read loud on speakers... up to here everything is working... but if while he is selecting a text a new event happens and the log is updated, the selected text sometimes is lost or is messed up.

Is there a way to detect when he is selecting text? So I can't stop updating while he select text. (And I don't mean to check if the selected text lenght is higher than 0, because sometimes I'd want to keep text selected and neither I want to check if mouse is down because sometimes he uses shift key + arrows to select text)

Comment: How are you implementing this .. javascript on website? Java applet? ... we need to know before advising you

Comment: Use the SelectionChanged event on the text box.

Answer (score 2):

like Mangist has suggested, you can use the SelectionChanged event and "pause" the updating of the textbox.

or

before you update the textbox, you could run a simple check.  for example

if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Equals(string.Empty))
{
update
}
else
{
dont update
}

Comment: Then when SelectionChanged is triggered I pause the updating, but how can I detect when the selection ends to start updating again?

Comment: you can do something simple like when SelectionChanged, check the richTextBox1.SelectedText value.  If it is empty (nothing selected or selection cleared) then start updating again, if it is not empty (selection made) then pause.

personally though, i would update the textbox in a thread and pause and resume using the thread.